# Change content in tooltip dynamically

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-tooltip

Here I have this code:

```
 $(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip({
      items: ".draggable ui-draggable ui-resizable",
      track: true,
      content: function(){
      var time = $( this ).width();
      if(time<0) {
    time = 0;
}

var seconds = time%60;
var minutes = (time-seconds)/60;
var output;

if(minutes >= 10) {
    output = ""+minutes;
} else {
    output = "0"+minutes;
}
output += ":";
if(seconds >= 10) {
    output += seconds;
} else {
    output += "0"+seconds;
}

return output;
      }
    });
  });
```

`.draggable` class is also draggable and resizable, and I need to show dynamically changed content in tooltip (time hh/min)

How I can dynamically change content in a tooltip?

Demo: http://jsbin.com/erofot/119

Why tooltip content won't to change dynamically when I resize the div ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the content is only updated everytime the tooltip shows.  You need to update the content every time the div is resized.

Create a function for updating the contents as follows:

```
function updateTooltipContent() {
    var time = $(this).width();
    if (time < 0) {
        time = 0;
    }

    var seconds = time % 60;
    var minutes = (time - seconds) / 60;
    var output;

    if (minutes >= 10) {
        output = "" + minutes;
    } else {
        output = "0" + minutes;
    }
    output += "h ";
    if (seconds >= 10) {
        output += seconds;
    } else {
        output += "0" + seconds;
    }

    return output + "min";
}
```

In your .resizable initialization, set the resize argument to updateTooltipContent as follows:

```
// 3 make the clone resizable
.resizable({
resize: function(event, ui) {
    var $this = $(event.currentTarget);
    $this.tooltip('option', 'content', updateTooltipContent);
}
```

Finally, in your tooltip initialization, set content to updateTooltipContent as follows:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).tooltip({
        items: ".draggable",
        track: true,
        content: updateTooltipContent
    });
});
```

**Edit:** Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abduncan/s6LxA/).

Comment: somwhere is error in .resizable({
resize: function(event, ui) {
    var $this = $(event.currentTarget);
    $this.tooltip('option', 'content', updateTooltipContent);
}

Comment: Check out the fiddle I added.  It shows the code functioning.

Comment: yes thanks, but when I add ths code into mine http://jsfiddle.net/s6LxA/2/ nothing wont to work

Comment: yes thanks, but when I add this code into mine http://jsfiddle.net/s6LxA/2/, nothing wont to work http://jsfiddle.net/s6LxA/2/

Comment: There were some brackets, semicolons, and parentheses in the wrong place in your version.  I cleaned it up http://jsfiddle.net/abduncan/s6LxA/